# Thirteen-point conic and four-point line, are they new?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, terminology, projective-geometry, plane-geometry, conic-sections

We know that [Five points determine a conic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_points_determine_a_conic) and [Two Points Determine a Line](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TwoPointsDetermineALine/). Here I found a simple construct of a conic through $7$ points (in PS I note that how the conic through thirteen points) and a line through $4$ points as follows:

> *Let $ABC$ be a triangle and $P$ be arbitrary point in the plane, let $A'$, $B'$, $C'$ lie on the line through $P$ and parallel to $BC$, $CA$, $AB$ respectively such that $AA' \parallel BB' \parallel CC'$. I am looking for a proof that*

> - *Seven points $A$, $B$, $C$, $A'$, $B'$, $C'$ and $P$ lie on a conic*
> - *Four points: midpoints of $AA'$, $BB'$, $CC'$ and center of the conic are collinear?*

[image]

PS: Three lines: The line through midpoints of $BC$ and $PA'$, The line through midpoints of $CA$ and $PB'$ and The line through midpoints of $AB$ and $PC'$ are concurrent at the center of the conic (denote the point of concurrence is $O$). Then easily show that reflection of $A, B, C, A', B', C'$ in $O$ also lie on the conic. This mean the conic through $13$ points.

**See also:**

- [Nine-point conic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-point_conic)
- [Dao's theorem (conics)](https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%90%E1%BB%8Bnh_l%C3%BD_%C4%90%C3%A0o_(conic))
- [Hexagons with Opposite Sides Parallel](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3621413?seq=1)

Comment: One triangle has only one its circumcircle, so we can not replace conic by circle in here, it is random, probability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a systematic method to solve problems of this sort (the $p,q$ method) by reducing them to computations which can be done by hand.  Assume the vertices are $(0,0), (1,0), (p,q)$. The three new points have the form $(x+t(p-1),y+tq), (x-up,y-uq), (x+s,y)$ with three parameters.These can be reduced to one free parameter by the parallelism condition.  One then uses the condition on the rank of the matrix with rows $$(x^2  ,xy , y^2 ,x ,y, 1)$$
one for each of the seven points, which ensures that they line on a conic.  Now compute the quadratic equation of the corresponding conic (with coefficients which depend on $p,q,x,y$).  It is then routine to compute the coordinates of $O$ and verify the collinearity condition.

This is, of course, not as elegant as a (presumable) synthetic proof but it has the advantage of placing the result in a general context.  It often suggests possible refinements (in this case I would try replacing the parallelism condition by suitable restraints on the angles between the three directions).